# How can i Initiate a Joget process from an asp.net archiving system & send extra parameters during the API call

Tags: asp.net, json, api, rest

I am working on a BPM tools named Joget, which offers an API to start its business processes from external systems. The API which it offers to start a process is `web/json/workflow/process/start/(*:processDefId).`

Now one of my clients have an archiving system based on asp.net , the system in general allow to scan an image , image processing g it and finally save it to the database.

So i need to integrate the archiving system with the Joget workflow, so that after archiving the document to initiate the Joget workflow . I read about the API that allow to start a process instant from external tool (in my case the asp.net archiving system), but this raise two question in my mind:-

1. how will the archiving system knows the Joget `processDefId` to send it  as part of the API call; should this for example be manually defined ?.
2. how can i access the archived document from inside the Joget workflow; should i for example send the archived document URL during the API call , IF yes , how can i do this since i can only send the "(*:processDefId) " when calling the start process API.

BR

Answer (score 0):

1. Manual definition is one option. But a better option would be to store the processDefId in a database parameter table.
2. I would suggest to separate two databases, the workflow database which contains workflow variables and application database which store any other information. You could send workflow variables during start process API sucah as web/json/workflow/process/start/(:processDefId)?var_A=value&var_B=value where A and B are defined as workflow variables in the process definition.